# Populate the select tag with models that another model belongs to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got two models - `Product` and `ProductCategory`. `Product` belongs to `ProductCategory`, and product category can have many products as well. Now I'm trying to make a select tag in the form for creating a new `Product`, where I would pick a category and set this new product to belong to that category, but I'm confused a lot how to do that. In my controller I have

```
def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.save
    redirect_to products_path
end

private

def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :price, :product_category_id)
end
```

And in my view I tried to do something like this:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :product_category_ids, ProductCategory.all, :id, :name, 
                                                          {multiple: true} %>
<% end %>
```

But I've got the following error

```
undefined method `product_category_ids' for #<Product:0x007f4982afa758>
```

How should I make this select tag to work?

**ADDED**

I've also tried to make in such a way:

```
<%= f.select :product_category_id, ProductCategory.all.collect { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, include_blank: true %>
```

But it returned me just an emptry `option` tag.

Comment: You should use `nested_form`  to create product belongs to a productCategory. For more details visit https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: @Udaykumardas I've looked through a documentation, the thing is that I need something in reverse -- I have a `Product` that belongs to a `ProductCategory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try this:

`product_category_ids` is not the column of `product` model

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :product_category_id, ProductCategory.all, :id, :name, 
                                                          {multiple: true} %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: There's no error, it just returns me an empty `select` tag. Though in my server logs I can see a request `SELECT "product_categories".* FROM "product_categories"`

Comment: Did ProductCategory table have datas?